# How to put several rectangles with text on top of an image with CSS?

Tags: css

I have an image and on top of it, I must put the following strip as shown in the image, where you will have a text and an icon with Fontawesome. The problem is that no matter how much I put z-index and so on, it does not work for me.

[image: Sample image]

I would like to know how to do it in an efficient way. Thank you!

Edit:

I tried it: https://jsfiddle.net/h82jy7e4/3/

**HTML**

```
<html>

<img class="image" src="http://www.ecosdelcombeima.com/sites/default/files/1_345.jpg">
<div class="frange">

</div>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.image{
width: 641px;
height: 332px;
z-index: 0;
}

.frange{
  width: 641px;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: kindly attach your code snippet

Comment: Sorry, it happened to attach me. I already edit the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this, you would need to define a container to hold the image and the bottom bar, and set a `position:absolute` on the bottom bar, and `position: relative` on the container; then you can add just a few more rules to get the look you want;

I added the green border so you can see that the image is in fact 'behind' the bottom bar

```css
.imagebox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.bottom-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom-bar button {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagebox">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x250">
  <div class="bottom-bar">
    <button>icon</button>
    <div>Here goes the text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. In this way, I was able to adapt it to the project. Use the positions!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already working, you just need to add the icon and the text inside of your div. Right now you just have an empty gray rectangle at the bottom of the image.

Also, note that z-index does not do anything unless the element is being positioned. You can remove both z-indexes from your code, as they are not necessary. You can read more about that here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

EDIT: I believe this is the solution you are looking for.

Inside your div, you need to create a span for the logo so it does not go on a new line, and so you can add the red background for the logo without changing the gray background for the rest of the div. Make sure you link to Font Awesome or the icon will not appear.

```
<span><i class="fas fa-images"></i></span>
<p>Selección colombia</p>
```

For formatting, your CSS would look like this

```
.frange{
    width: 641px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    margin-top: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
}

.fa-images{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

span{
    background-color: red;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

p{
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: But if you notice, the icon is inside a rectangle with a background. That's why I would have to have two rectangles and one on top of the other, right?

Comment: In order to have the background color of the icon be a different color from the div, you would need to add a new element for your icon. I've edited my post to help you out. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
.image{
    width: 641px;
    height: 332px;
    position: relative;
}`

.frange{
    width: 641px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 55%;
}
```

Also by setting left, right, top you can move the block.